# System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede agregar un control de nivel superior a un control.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
        lblTitulo.Text = "Inicio";
        this.Pnlcarga.Controls.Clear();
        Inicio Inicio_vrb = new Inicio();
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        TopLevel = false;
        TopMost = true;
        Inicio_vrb.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.PnlFormLoader.Controls.Add(Inicio_vrb);
        Inicio_vrb.Show();
```

No termino de entender el error ni como solucionarlo la verdad.
Apenas ejecuto el codigo salta "System.ArgumentException: 'No se puede agregar un control de nivel superior a un control.'"

Comment: que tipo de control es Inicio?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Es un control compuesto de windows forms

Comment: o sea, es un windows forms, un windows forms no puede ser hijo de ningun control...